# Help identifying this 1x1 2/3 brick (no studs)

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I have been trying to identify this 1x1 2/3 (?) brick (looked in Studio, Bricklink parts list, sets, ...) and cannot, for the life of me, identify it. I have been able to find a picture of it and know it exists at least in white and light gray. The closest I got was [49307](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=49307&name=Brick,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20x%202/3%20No%20Studs,%20Curved%20Top&category=%5BBrick,%20Modified%5D#T=C)

[image: Lego mosaic wall]

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that you are seeing the wide end of a cheese slope like this:

[image: Cheese slopes laid out together]

Note that these are simply held in place by friction and not really "connected" in a traditional way.

Comment: Ah that explains why i could not find it, i have checked in software and the dimensions of the cheese slope (54200) indeed seem to be correct. I never noticed they were rounded enough around the edges (backside) to given enough "rounding" effect when reversed.

Thanks a lot!